# multiplayer game in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, multiplayer, glut

what is the easiest way how to make network communication in openGL/glut? Does anybody know any good tutorial for beginners? thanks

(or is there any simpler way then openGL?)

Comment: @Elliott has it right. Also "Where to start" or "Which technology" questions are off-topic for this site because answers are based largely on opinions rather than facts. You can read more about in the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) or in what this site is [About](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

you are looking into the wrong things i'm afraid. OpenGL  is a graphics library and has nothing to do with network communications.

You best bet would be to look up tutorials on network communication examples for the programming language you are using to write your program in

Comment: obviously the programming language is c++

Comment: Well I was just trying to make the answer a little bit more general so that if anyone else has the same sort of question they would know what to look for even if the language is different to C++